# packing of bits in fixed length format

Tags: c++, bit

I am working on an application in which we are going to send a message from client to a server. The message will have 64 fields and these fields will be copied in a single character string through TCP socket connection. The message may not contain all the 64 fields. So in order to resolve this problem there will be a field before all these 64 field which will be 8 character long which will contain information about these fields that is which field is present and which field is not. The problem currently I am facing is that suppose if I have 1st, 3rd and 5th bit is set the length will be come of that bit map will be 1 and when copying it to the character string which is going to be send to Server only 1 character string reaches there as from second onwards it used to have '\0'. And if I put '0' in rest of the space(which is from 2nd to 8) and getting other fields as well set (See the output). So my question is, is there any way I keep the length of the string as exactly 8 and it won'y set any other bit as well so that server can extract correct message. Just iterating it one more time, the message format is 8 character long bit map and then the entire packed message of 64 fields.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#define ISO_LEN 64
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i ;
    bool    bitmap[ISO_LEN];
    for(i = 0; i  < ISO_LEN; i++)
    {
         bitmap[i] = false;
    }

    bitmap[1] = true; bitmap[3] = true; bitmap[5] = true;
    unsigned char bmap[ISO_LEN/8 + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < ISO_LEN/8; bmap[i++] = 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < ISO_LEN; i++)
    {
        if (bitmap[i])
        {
            bmap[i/8] |= (unsigned char)(0x80 >> (i%8));
        }
    }
//  intentional effort to make the length exactly 8
    int start = strlen(bmap);
    for (int i = start; i < ISO_LEN/8 ; i++)
    {
        bmap[i] = '0';
    }
//  ends

    char *sendee = new char[1000];
    memcpy(sendee , bmap, ISO_LEN/8); 

    for (int i = 0; i < ISO_LEN; i++) 
    {
        if (sendee[i/8] & ((unsigned char)0x80 >>  (i % 8))) 
        {
                   cout<<i<<"th bit is true\n";
        }
        else
        {
                   cout<<i<<"th bit is false\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

Output:
0th bit is false
1th bit is true
2th bit is false
3th bit is true
4th bit is false
5th bit is true
6th bit is false
7th bit is false
8th bit is false
9th bit is false
10th bit is true
11th bit is true
12th bit is false
13th bit is false
14th bit is false
15th bit is false
16th bit is false
17th bit is false
18th bit is true
19th bit is true
20th bit is false
21th bit is false
22th bit is false
23th bit is false
24th bit is false
25th bit is false
26th bit is true
27th bit is true
28th bit is false
29th bit is false
30th bit is false
31th bit is false
32th bit is false
33th bit is false
34th bit is true
35th bit is true
36th bit is false
37th bit is false
38th bit is false
39th bit is false
40th bit is false
41th bit is false
42th bit is true
43th bit is true
44th bit is false
45th bit is false
46th bit is false
47th bit is false
48th bit is false
49th bit is false
50th bit is true
51th bit is true
52th bit is false
53th bit is false
54th bit is false
55th bit is false
56th bit is false
57th bit is false
58th bit is true
59th bit is true
60th bit is false
61th bit is false
62th bit is false
63th bit is false
```

Comment: // Indeed, comments are only for the comment section! ;)

Comment: @Cornstalks I removed those innocuous // which seems obnoxious to you .

Comment: Do you control the client and the server? In that case, if you wish to optimize the quantity of information sent, why not just send two 32-bit unsigned int (or one 64-bit unsigned long int)? The way I'm understanding this (and I might be wrong) is that you're sending 8 bytes (so essentially 64 bits) to describe how you're not going to send all 64 bits, and then you send more bits?

Comment: Ok , so I need to send from 0 to 63 fields . It may not contain all the fields . The field 12 will contain date (6 characters), field 6 will contain time(4 characters) , field 45 will have device number similarly there will be other fields as well . Depending upon the field number the server will calculate the length of that particular field .Then after reading entire message and after its processing it will send the message to the client in that same format , then client will read that message and then respond until communication ends depending upon the problem .Let me knw if u hv any quest

Comment: @Martin , let me know if u understood the problem . In order to make it more clear I just want an 8 character string which doen't contain '\0' and only those bits set in them which I set and not set automatically .

Comment: @Thomas , those // have been removed . Thank you .

Comment: What do you mean set automatically? The only reason you are getting `true` on  bit 18 and 19 etc is because you are setting `bmap[i] = '0';` ('0' is the same as 48). Remove that loop or set it to `0` instead.

Comment: @super , If I remove that loop and set it to 0 which I already did while initializing it (for (int i = 0; i < ISO_LEN/8; bmap[i++] = 0);) , the length of the string becomes less that 8 , as it contains '\0' in those rest of the fields due to which only the bitmap is reaching the server and not the entire message . I guess I already mentioned that in the question itself . Kindly read the entire question .

Comment: @user3798283 The lenght of an array doesn't change when you put a `\0` in it. The `\0` is only there to tell for example output with `cout` where the string ends. If you are sending it over a network that's completely irrelevant. You can obviously send a byte with the value of `0` (or `\0`) over the network just fine.

Comment: @super Well in my case only bitmap is reaching .

Comment: @user3798283 I think I understand your problem. You should DEFINITELY take a look at [Google's protobuffer](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/). It does exactly what you want, and then some. You could declare all the fields in you packet, and protobuf will only encode the fields you are actually sending. And they'll be packed automatically the most efficient way. On the other side, protobuf parses those fields automatically. We used that for a communication project, and it's wonderful.

Comment: @user3798283 I seems to me that is what you should be asking about. How are you sending the data?

Comment: @super I am using normal send (ssize_t send(int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t len, int flags);) and recv () of unix . And when I filling the bitmap with 8 characters the bitmap as well as the message is reaching to the server but again some other bits are also getting set which is causing the processing of message wrong and when it is less than 8 then only bitmap is going and the sole reason is '\0' only . Even when I am running both client and server code in debug mode when I am printing sendee on the client side it is giving bitmap only when it is less than 8, and sendee + 8 will print ms

Comment: @super I am using normal send (ssize_t send(int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t len, int flags);) and recv () of unix . And when I filling the bitmap with 8 characters the bitmap as well as the message is reaching to the server but again some other bits are also getting set which is causing the processing of message wrong and when it is less than 8 then only bitmap is going and the sole reason is '\0' only . Even when I am running both client and server code in debug mode when I am printing sendee on the client side it is giving bitmap only when it is less than 8, and sendee + 8 will print ms

Comment: @Martin thanks for the suggestion , but is there any way I can do this without using any external library like you suggested.

Comment: @user3798283 Yes, it's possible. There's no real "bad way" to send the data you need. It's just that with this technique, you're going to send as much as three times more data than needed, you'll have all sort of bugs because of corner-cases you didn't think of, and you're going to have a hard time maintaining it if the message's structure ever change.

Comment: @user3798283 In that call you specify the length of you buffer. The reason is still not \0, more likely you are trying to use strlen(sendee) or similar and then use that as len. If you specify the correct size it should all send.